# Google Analytics API - ecommerce returns empty EcommerceData object

Tags: e-commerce, google-analytics-api

For some reason the object remains empty, ecommerce and enhanced ecommerce settings are enabled.
the request:

```
body = {
            "viewId": VIEW_ID,
            "user": {
                "type": "CLIENT_ID",
                "userId": "414884771.1598953392"
            },
            "activityTypes": "ECOMMERCE",
            "dateRange": {
                "startDate": "2020-09-01",
                "endDate": "2020-10-30",
            },
            "pageSize":100,
        }
```

and a row of response:

```
{'sessions': [{'sessionId': '160032xxxxxx', 'deviceCategory': 'mobile', 'platform': 'iOS', 'dataSource': 'web', 'activities': [{'activityTime': '2020-09-17T05:22:33.257619Z', 'source': '(direct)', 'medium': '(none)', 'channelGrouping': 'Direct', 'campaign': '(not set)', 'keyword': '(not set)', 'hostname': 'xxxxxxx.xx', 'landingPagePath': '/', 'activityType': 'ECOMMERCE', 'ecommerce': {}}]
```

any suggestions as to why 'ecommerce' : {}} remains empty are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this is a reported bug. Unfortunately, it has been open for 1y+ :(
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139107430